# Session not persisting

Tags: php, session

I'm unable to get any session data to persist across my app. I'm using a cart package and after adding the items the cart is immediately empty when I try to retrieve the data in another page.

I've tested the session by creating a test session and then retrieving that. It works if I retrieve it immediately but if I call the session on another page it no longer works

I've read similar threads and have my session config file set as:

```
driver => native
lifetime => 120
expire_on_close => true
domain => false`
```

There's no output ie echo statements before redirects. I've tried doing a fresh install but still the same problems. This is currently on a local server - localhost with a url of test.loc

Comment: Are you sure your browser stores the session cookie and sends it back on the next request? Use your browsers network debugging tool to loo for `Set-Cookie` and `Cookie` headers or whatever other way your browser provides.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if PHP is trying to save to a path that is not writable/doesn't exist.

Try the following code to check where PHP is trying to save session files:

```
<?php
echo ini_get('session.save_path');
?>
```

Then check that folder to see if a) it exists and b) if session files are being written into it.

If it doesn't exist you need to change the .ini file or use `ini_set('session.save_path')` to change where PHP is trying to save session info. If the folder does exist it may be a permissions issue.

Finally, it may be a cookie issue - try using the app with different browsers, and check that the browsers have cookies enabled.